# best way to write simple code test in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, solution

I don't know if someone has already asked this simple question earlier as well. So, the question is I have a simple code test for one of my assignment, I want to use C# to solve the problem, and I am wondering if I build a new solution in C# with the main method to run the code within the solution, then it will contain probably an sln file and also csproj file and some other files as well. So will it be wise to submit the entire solution as zipping or upload in a repo for an assignment, or there are some other smarter ways to submit a code assignment while coding in visual studio in C#.
I don't want a logic or code for my assignment, I just expertise ideas I would say as I more of intermediate in .NET 
TIA

Comment: you want to compress of code in better way.

Comment: ask your teacher how he/she expects your programs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how your tutor is expecting / willing to receive it?
The modern (and arguably best in my opinion) way would be to push it to a repo. Otherwise you could go old school and zip up the whole folder structure (minus the bin and obj folders).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better to keep code in one file.

You could try the [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor to create one-file programs.
Or use the online C# compilers ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_csharp_compiler)). I personally use the online compilers, and then just store the code on my computer in `*.cs` files.

Answer (score 0):

Just zip your whole project and upload it to the google drive. After uploading it into the drive you will get an option of sharing setting and through that you can feed the email id of the person whom you want to send it.. That link will be sent to that person and he/she can download it easily...